# Can you "partially" derive a Typeclass?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

In the following toy example we create a new type `D` for which we want to implement the typeclass `Show`. Now let's say for all constructors the derived `show` function would be just fine, except for one special case `A` for which we want to override that default.

Is it possible to do that, or can you just have *all* or *none* of them derived?

```hs
data D = A | B | C
  deriving (Show)

-- goal: 
-- show A = "A is special"
-- show B = "B"
-- show C = "C"

main = print $ show A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PyWxJFHBRcFWwVGhRsEJiJ25FBRSUosyyzLz0hU0gjPyyzW5uHR1FdLzE3OsFECsYqAYULmtgpKjQmaxQnFBanJmYo4SXMoJJOWE4DuD@M5KXFy5iZl5QHZBUWZeiYIK1Jz//wE)

Answer (score 13):

This can be done using generics. `generic-data` provides a default implementation of `showsPrec`, `gshowsPrec`, and you can use pattern-matching to handle non-default cases before it:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
import GHC.Generics
import Generic.Data (gshowsPrec)

data D = A | B | C
  deriving (Generic)

instance Show D where
  showsPrec _ A = ("A is special" ++)
  showsPrec n x = gshowsPrec n x
```